# Change bar chart to line chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization

As I am converting all these bar charts to line chart in the following visualization.

I have added appended snippet to my code in buildAlpha function which is creating all the bars related to visualization.

However, I am not able to see either a path or line tag in DOM.

Please help me to change all these bar charts to line charts and adding y-axis to respective charts

[image: Snapshot]

```
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return axes.timeX(new Date(d.date));
            })
            .y(function (d, i, j) {
                return axes[keys[j] + 'Y'](d[keys[j]]);
            })
            .interpolate("basis");

        var area = d3.svg.area()
            .x(function (d) {
                return axes.timeX(new Date(d.date));
            })
            .y0(108)
            .y1(function (d) {
                return axes[keys[j] + 'Y'](d[keys[j]]);
            });

        bars.append("path")
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area);

        bars.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function (d, i) {
                return line(d['Air']);
            });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/wjqd58bt/)

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/mm9m1ttp/1/) with Line Chart.

However not able to get that mouseover line and tooltip which is availiable in bar chart

Comment: Please advice if there is any other further information required. Thank You !

Comment: idk why, but I can't fork or update you jsfiddle :/

Comment: I have updated just like any other fiddle which I have shared earlier, Is there any settings I have to change

Comment: Try this link https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/wjqd58bt/2/

Comment: Still not, I get redirected to the jsfiddle root whenclicking update or fork. Anyhow, the problem is that you do not use the appropriate group to render the line/area. You should use `barWraps` instead of `bars`, so that you get access to the full data array.

Comment: PS: my twitter handle is on my profile, thanks for visiting my blog anyway :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152733/discussion-between-harsha-vardhan-and-hugues-stefanski).

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't even work.

Comment: Following is the updated  fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/mm9m1ttp/1/

Comment: Well, those seem to be line charts to me... what's your question then?

Comment: However Mouseoverline and tooltip is missing ? For reference, check the mousoverline for barcharts in attached snapshot

Comment: If you need any other information, please advice .

Comment: Working example at https://jsfiddle.net/mm9m1ttp/6/

Comment: You have fixed the y-scale domain same for all the charts to [0,100]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated jsfiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mm9m1ttp/7/). Besides the line chart part, I did the following steps:

#### Create a `scales` object to get one scale per chart:

```
var scales = {};
fields.forEach(function(f){
  var currentData  = test.filter(function(d){return d.name===f;})[0].data;
  scales[f]= d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(currentData, function(d) {return d.value})])
               .range([lineHeight, 0])
               .nice();
 });
```

#### Add a `mousemove` to the dispatch:

```
var dispatch = d3.dispatch('hideTooltip', 'iTooltip', 'mousemove');
```

#### Append a text to each chart to display the tooltip:

```
alphaWrap.append('text')
        .classed('tooltip', true)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .style('fill', function(d){return colorScale(d.name)});
```

#### Append a `rect` on each chart to subscribe to the `mousemove` event.

When the mouse moves, I get its position, compute the corresponding date, and dispatch it:

```
alphaWrap.append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', xScale.range()[1])
        .attr('height', lineHeight)
        .style('pointer-events', 'all')
        .style('fill', 'transparent')
        .on('mousemove', function(d,i){
            var mouse=d3.mouse(this);
            var date = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
            dispatch.mousemove(date);
        });
```

#### Append a line over all 3 charts:

```
d3.select('#chart-container')
      .append('line')
      .classed('tooltip', 'true')
      .style('stroke', 'darkgray')
      .attr('x1',90)
      .attr('x2',90)
      .attr('y1',0)
      .attr('y2',fields.length*plotHeight);
```

#### React to the `dispatch` `mousemove` event

I created a [`bisector`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_bisector) to find the index of the closest date in the array of data for the chart.
Thanks the date and, the bisector, the line can be moved appropriately, and the value of the tooltip can be displayed

```
var bisector = d3.bisector(function(d){return d.date}).right;
dispatch.on('mousemove', function(date){
  d3.select('line.tooltip')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+xScale(date)+',0)')
  alphaWrap.select('text.tooltip')
        .attr('transform', function(d,i){
          var value = bisector(d.data, date);
          return 'translate('+xScale(date)+','+scales[d.name](d.data[value].value)+')';
        })
        .text(function(d,i){
          var value = bisector(d.data, date);
          return d3.format('2.2f')(d.data[value].value);
        });
    });
```